# Can I construct base class to allocate while initializing derived class?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I'm making this program assignment. So I can't change header file. That means I can't make get() or set() functions.

Below code is header of Base class I'm using

```
#include "IShape.h"
#include <vector>

class Polygon : public IShape {
private:
    std::vector<Point> points;
public:
    Polygon() = default;
    Polygon(const Point& one, const Point& two, const Point& three);
    Polygon(const std::vector<Point>& points);
    Polygon(const Polygon& polygon);
    virtual ~Polygon() {
      std::cout << "Polygon is destructed!" << std::endl;
    };

    virtual bool contain(Point p) const override;
    virtual double getPerimeter() const override;
    virtual double getArea() const override;

    //https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual - covariant return types
    //Since the return value is a pointer or reference to a derived class (child class) of IShape,
    //the clone() function can be overridden
    virtual Polygon* clone() const override {
        return new Polygon(*this);
    };

protected:
    virtual std::ostream& toString(std::ostream& os) const override;
};
```

IShape, which is base class of Ishape, consist of pure virtual functions.

Problem is down below.

```
#include "Polygon.h"

class Rectangle final : public Polygon {
private:
    std::ostream &toString(std::ostream &os) const override;
public:
    Rectangle() = default;
    Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4);
    Rectangle(const std::vector<Point> points) : Polygon(points) {};
    virtual ~Rectangle() {
      std::cout << "Rectangle is destructed!" << std::endl;
    }

    double getPerimeter() const override;
    double getArea() const override;
    Rectangle *clone() const override;
    bool contain(Point p) const override;

};
```

What I'd like to ask is when I initialize using `Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)`, I need to make vector which declared in Polygon class.

I can't change it directly given that it is member variable, and I can't use initialization list because vector is not transferred to it.

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)
{
    vector<Point> temp_vec;
    temp_vec.push_back(p2);
    temp_vec.push_back(p1);
    temp_vec.push_back(p3);
    temp_vec.push_back(p4);
    Polygon(temp_vec);
}
```

Above code is what I thought. But compiler says `error: conflicting declaration 'Polygon temp_vec'`

Can you give me any advice for me? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered adding the points to `points`?  Unrelated but worth thinking about ... four points do not define a rectangle.

Comment: Yes i did considered that but as I mentioned up there I cannot modify header because it is an assignment. But thank you for your advice :)

Comment: You can add them to `points` in **your** constructor ...

Comment: Oh really? Can you show it with a code?

Comment: @donkopotamus `points` is `private`. Subclasses can't access it without an accessor function in the base class, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I should have been paying more attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `static` helper function to make `temp_vec`, like this:

```
static std::vector<Point> get_temp_vec(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
    std::vector<Point> temp_vec;
    temp_vec.push_back(p2);
    temp_vec.push_back(p1);
    temp_vec.push_back(p3);
    temp_vec.push_back(p4);
    return temp_vec;
}
```

Then make your constructor use it like this:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) : Polygon(get_temp_vec(p1, p2, p3, p4)) {}
```

---

Also, I'm not sure what "I can't use initialization list because vector is not transferred to it" means, but this works fine when I try it:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) : Polygon(std::vector<Point>{p2, p1, p3, p4}) {}
```

The above technique would still be useful in other cases where this wouldn't work, though.

Comment: Oh it works! I didn't actually try initialization list ```Polygon(std::vector<Point>{p2, p1, p3, p4})``` this way. I only tried ```Polygon(std::vector<Point>)```. That was stupid. Thanks a lot!

Comment: About static function though, I don't get static keywords exactly yet. So to tell you as far as I can understood, static function makes function to remain in memory section, thus allow to access it's value even after the function is terminated. Is this right?

Comment: @이가원 `static` means different things depending on where it's used. When used on a member function, it means you don't need an object to call it and there's no `this` pointer available to it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for answering. Maybe I should look for that by myself.